# Excel2016 vba Format function on Windows 10 produces unexpected time separator

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, vba

Code below used to give requested time separator, but now Excel2016 on Windows 10 produces wrong result.

```
Public Sub TestDateFormat()
    Dim s As String
    Dim d As Date

    d = Now()
    s = Format(d, "yyyy.mm.dd Hh:Nn:Ss")
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

============================================

TestDateFormat

> 2018.11.08 13.43.26

Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.17134
Excel for Office version 16.0.11001.20074

Someone else has this?

Comment: Win10, Excel2016 (desktop) - works on my machine. Sorry. Are you running Office365?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the vba function. Format seems to be using given special delimiter for date, but delimiter from regional settings for time! OMG!

Answer (score 0):

Use a date cell for storing the date in the format you want:

```
cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(Format(d, "yyyy.mm.dd Hh:Nn:Ss")), ".", ":", 1, 2))